# Per client ssl certificate

Tags: c#, ssl

So I have my little server and client, since I have multiple users connecting I would like to have each user have his/her own Ssl certificate which is used for the SslStream.
So basically the server has a public key for each client, the client has his private key, when the client connects it will start an SslStream with those certificates, but the problem is, the server does not know which certificate should be loaded as it doesnt know what client is connecting, this is my server code:

```
while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
                requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                bool leaveInnerStreamOpen = false;
                RemoteCertificateValidationCallback validationCallback =
                  new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ClientValidationCallback);
                LocalCertificateSelectionCallback selectionCallback =
                  new LocalCertificateSelectionCallback(ServerCertificateSelectionCallback);
                EncryptionPolicy encryptionPolicy = EncryptionPolicy.AllowNoEncryption;
                _sslStream = new SslStream(clientSocket.GetStream(),
                  leaveInnerStreamOpen, validationCallback, selectionCallback, encryptionPolicy);
                X509Certificate2 certificate = ServerCertificate.Servercertificate();
                bool requireClientCertificate = false;
                SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12;
                bool checkCertificateRevocation = true;
                _sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer
                  (certificate, requireClientCertificate, enabledSslProtocols, checkCertificateRevocation);
                buffer = new byte[4];
                int readBytes = _sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4);
                if (readBytes == 0)
                    break;
                int MessageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
                byte[] bufferreader = new byte[MessageSize];
                clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize = MessageSize;
                readBytes = _sslStream.Read(bufferreader, 0, MessageSize);
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(MessageSize));
                rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);
                dataFromClient = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bufferreader);
                byte[] outbuffer = new byte[4];
                serverResponse = R.Respond(dataFromClient, clientSocket);
                sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                outbuffer = new byte[4];
                outbuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(sendBytes.Length);
                _sslStream.Write(outbuffer, 0, 4);
                _sslStream.Flush();
                clientSocket.SendBufferSize = sendBytes.Length;
                _sslStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                _sslStream.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EndPointHandler.RemoveEndPoint(clientSocket);
                clientSocket.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("User Server >> " + ex.ToString());
                Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
            }
        }
```

So what should happen is that first the client sends his username, the server then looks for a matching certificate. It then authenticates itself with that public certificate and client authenticates with the private certificate, but the problem is that I dont exactly know how to do that and sadly a lot of google searches resulted in nothing.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Can you use IIS? If so, IIS has a feature that allows to map client certificates to user accounts, either through AD, if on a domain, or through explicit mappings in IIS. To hand-roll this functionality sounds questionable but if you have to, the SSL negotiation should take place first as per usual and if successful, the client would need to send its username + a signature created with that user's private key. You would then look up the public key for that username and validate the signature.

Comment: Thanks, I know about IIS but i'm afraid I cant use it for this. Okay that sounds like a good idea but is it then possible to te reset the ssl connection to use the user's certificate? Because it is not really ment for authentication, the user still has his own password to enter but the certificate is to ensure a really private connection using his certificate